# Loop array to create HTML elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Ruby on Rails 3.2. I am trying to create multiple hidden field tag based on a defined array. Below is my code:

```
# shop.rb
...
ADDRESS_COMPONENTS = ['lat', 'lng', 'name']
...

# shops_helper.rb
module ShopsHelper
  def address_components_hidden_fields
    Shop::ADDRESS_COMPONENTS.each do |address_component|
      hidden_field_tag(address_component, "")
    end
  end
end

# _form.html.erb
<%= address_components_hidden_fields %>
```

The output is:

```
['lat', 'lng', 'name']
```

I am expecting the output to be:

```
<input type='hidden' name='lat' id='lat' value='' />
<input type='hidden' name='lng' id='lng' value='' />
<input type='hidden' name='name' id='name' value='' />
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to concat the `hidden_field_tag` helpers together.

```
module ShopsHelper
  def address_components_hidden_fields
    Shop::ADDRESS_COMPONENTS.map do |address_component|
      hidden_field_tag(address_component, "")
    end.join("\n")
  end
end
```

Notice the usage of `map` and `join`.